# Getting connection close in http method GET in nodejs, express

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, nginx

Getting connection close header in response in request of method GET.
When sending request of method POST the connection is keep-alive

Current stack that i have is AWS ALB that pass the request to EKS. inside the EKS i have a NGINX ingress that route the request to a specific service.

All requests are of type POST and GET. all post request to the service keep the connection alive, request of GET close the connection.
When i force the header inside the response it is ignored.
when i use curl i get the following response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 10:22:03 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 15602
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: Express
```

When i run the command directly from inside the cluster directly to the NGINX (using busybox bod) i get the following response :

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 10:23:04 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 15602
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
```

help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue come i think from the ALB and from incorrect configuration of postman.

I had a problem in postman that i was sending empty json body: for example: {} because of leftover from previous debugs against POST method.
once i removed the empty json and sent a GET request the channel was left open.
If i change the and put the {} again although it is a GET request and there is no need for the body it close the channel.